# How to choose the most effective treatment?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, multiple-comparisons

I randomly assign subjects to $N$ different group and let each group take a different treatment (e.g., dose of a medicine). The treatment is labeled as $T_i$, where $i=1,2,...,N$. The metric I care about is a binary variable ($Y_i=0$), i.e., either the subject lives ($Y_i=1$) or dies ($Y_i=0$). So within each group, I have the fraction of people alive. My goal is to tell which treatment is the most effective one (based on this data).

First, I could run a chi-square test to check if I can reject $H_0:$ **all the treatments has the same effect.** But this result tells me nothing about which one is the most effective treatment. Then should I just look at the alive rate of each group and pick one with the highest value? But each group may have different number of subjects (even if all groups has the same number of subjects, is this procedure meaningful?)

Comment: One approach is subset selection: find a subset of the groups which have probability $\ge .95$, say, to contain the best group

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Could you please elaborate a little bit more?